# How to check css syntastic error with styleline?

Tags: node.js, npm, stylelint

To install styleline with npm.

```
sudo npm install -g stylelint
```

To install config file for stylelint.

```
sudo npm install stylelint-config-standard --save-dev -g 
npm WARN stylelint-config-standard@16.0.0 requires a peer of stylelint@^7.8.0 but none was installed.

+ stylelint-config-standard@16.0.0
added 1 package in 1.017s
```

Now to check a test.css file with stylelint.

```
$ stylelint   "/tmp/menu/test.css"  
Error: No configuration provided for /tmp/menu/test.css
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylelint/lib/utils/configurationError.js:8:27)
    at stylelint._fullExplorer.load.then.then.config (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylelint/lib/getConfigForFile.js:39:13)
    at <anonymous>
```

Why the issue arise --No configuration provided for /tmp/menu/test.css?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In according to `stylelint` configuration document.
You need to set your configuration object.

https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md